# How can I open a port on just one server IP?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, linux-networking

I am setting up a dedicated server for gameserver hosting, which will also host a couple of other server applications (such as a web server).
The dedicated server has a total of four IP addresses, let's say it's using the following:

- `192.0.2.0`;
- `192.0.2.1`;
- `192.0.2.2`;
- `192.0.2.3`

For security, I want each IP to be dedicated to a certain service/group of services (and for outbound ports to be completely open), for example:

- `192.0.2.0` (Game Servers);
- `192.0.2.1` (Teamspeak Server);
- `192.0.2.2` (Web server);
- `192.0.2.3` (system [SSH, etc.])

The order of events should be that **all ports are blocked**, then certain ports are unblocked. [I've looked here](https://www.garron.me/en/bits/iptables-open-port-for-specific-ip.html), and I have a rough ordered command-list to be turned into a bash script & set to execute on boot:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -s 192.0.2.3 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -s 192.0.2.3 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 192.0.2.3 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 192.0.2.0 --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 192.0.2.0 --dport 25566 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 192.0.2.2 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 192.0.2.1 --dport 9987 -j ACCEPT
```

*The two commands to allow all outbound traffic from [IPTables rule to allow all outbound locally originating traffic?](https://serverfault.com/questions/429400/iptables-rule-to-allow-all-outbound-locally-originating-traffic)*

Due to [my past experience with iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/631772/only-allow-a-connection-from-specific-domains), I'm reluctant to apply these rules as I'm unsure if they're correct, or if I'm approaching this in the correct way. Will the above iptables rules work as intended, and if not, how can I go about correcting it so it will work as intended?

The server runs Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. I do have a hardware firewall provided by my provider at my disposal, but it doesn't allow me to block/allow ports for specific IPs that the server has (so I'm unable to use it in this instance).

Comment: I had a mooch around my hosts' firewall configuration section of their control panel, and I've managed to get my desired configuration. However, I'd still like to know how to get the configuration working with iptables, for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your post, my assumption is:

In principle, all IP addresses can open outbound connections
No IP address should be reachable inbound by default.
All IP addresses are bound to a single physical network interface.

I would then configure this as follows:

```
#Block all incoming connections
iptables -P INPUT REJECT

#Allow all outgoing connections
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

#Allow all on local loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

#Allow established connections
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#Game server on TCP/25565 and TCP/25566
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 192.0.2.0 --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 192.0.2.0 --dport 25566 -j ACCEPT

#Teamspeak on TCP/9987 (No UDP?)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 192.0.2.1 --dport 9987 -j ACCEPT

#Web server
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 192.0.2.2 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

#System services
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 192.0.2.3 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Above and beyond that, why not use something like Shorewall to manage iptables rules?